# MySQL - Create Index Statement prints "[HY000][1880] TIME/TIMESTAMP/DATETIME columns of old format have been upgraded to the new format"

Tags: mysql

My database has a MyISAM table on a MySQL server using 5.6.41-log.
I created a composite index on the table that references a varchar column and a datetime column:

```
create index ix_orders_region_date on orders (region_code, order_date);
```

Upon execution, I received the following error message:

```
[HY000][1880] TIME/TIMESTAMP/DATETIME columns of old format have been upgraded to the new format.
```

The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-errors/5.6/en/server-error-reference.html) states that this error pertains to the symbol  ER_OLD_TEMPORALS_UPGRADED, but there is no further explanation.

I've established the following:

1. The create index statement succeeded and the index is being used by queries.
2. SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST doesn't show anything out of the ordinary and the application appears to be functioning.
3. There is nothing suspect in the error log.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible that the create index statement broke something?
2. If so, how do I diagnose what, if anything, is wrong?

Comment: Exceptions are thrown. This is an informational message, not an error, and certainly not an exception, and it was printed, not 'thrown'. Don't misuse standard terminology, and don't panic when a software program tells you something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The temporal datatypes (being `TIME`, `DATETIME`, and `TIMESTAMP`) support fractional values starting from MySQL 5.6.4, which means that the storage encoding is slightly different from what it is in older versions. Basic operations continue to be supported when using the old temporal columns, and they're automatically upgraded to the new format when a table containing the deprecated types has an `ALTER TABLE`, `FORCE`, or `CREATE INDEX` issued against it.

Historically I’ve not seen any issues where this automatic process results in data corruption or alteration. That said, you may want to look at updating all of the tables in the database to use the newer data type, as these changes came about [almost a decade ago](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-4.html). By updating the definitions, you’ll reduce the risk of unexpected failures later if you upgrade to a much newer version of MySQL that rejects the older format.

Comment: That's a relief, I never know what surprises these legacy systems have. Thanks.